# Dependency Injection when concrete class need to be swapped C#

Tags: c#

I am planning to write a shared file between that could be used between multiple projects.

My Projects:

1. Write code to eat Ice cream. (Because ice cream is my favorite food). 
   (Please note that my favorite food might change to Mango in the future)
2. Write code to eat Mango. (Because mango is my favorite food).
   (Please note that my favorite food might change to Ice cream in the future)

Following is the interface

```
interface IEatFavoriteFood
{
    void eat();
}
```

Following will be my concrete classes.

```
class EatMango
{
  void eat()
  {
   // Some code to eat mango
  }
}


class EatIceCream
{
  void eat()
  {
   // Some code to eat ice cream
  }
}
```

So, I will need to have two main programs separately for my two projects, since I will be initializing two different concrete classes for the `IEatFavoriteFood` interface to call `eat()`.

```
Main()
{
   IEatFavoriteFood iff = new EatMango();
   iff.eat();
}
```

and

```
Main()
{
   IEatFavoriteFood iff = new EatIceCream();
   iff.eat();
}
```

In addition to that, if sometime in the future the favorite food changes to Mango in the first project, then I will have to re-write the initialization and re-compile my project. Is there a better way to implement this functionality. Does using a config file in this case, makes better sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dependency injection to work, you need some place where the concrete types are listed, which knows which concrete class to plug into for your possible dependencies (the interface).

In dependency injection frameworks, this is often done with some kind of configuration, either via code or with some external files (e.g. some XML configuration).

For your purpose, it’s probably the easiest way to start simple and simply have some “central entity” that provides you with your dependencies. This could for example be a `FavoriteFoodFactory`:

```
public class FavoriteFoodFactory
{
    public static IEatFavoriteFood GetFavoriteFood()
    {
        return new EatIceCream();
    }
}
```

So in your `Main`, you would then just ask that factory to give you whatever favorite food is currently configured:

```
Main()
{
    IEatFavoriteFood iff = FavoriteFoodFactory.GetFavoriteFood();
    iff.eat();
}
```

Of course that just shifts the responsibility to create a concrete object to somewhere else, but that’s exactly the point of dependency injection. To have something at the very top that takes care of how to resolve a dependency, removing the *need to know* from the components further down.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use an IOC container like Autofac (http://autofac.org/), Ninject (http://www.ninject.org/) or whatever you like most. 
The container will provide you with different ways to handle that kind of scenario. 
For example, in Autofac you can create a module (that is a class containing the registrations of the concrete classes that will be used by the container) that can be loaded/selected via web.config or code. 
You can see a detailed documentation here with examples 
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html

Please note that using an IOC container can be easy, but in most cases you must be aware of the components lifecycle in order to avoid possible problems and memory leaking.